# List of ec2 instances attached to one of iam role with cloudshell,cli

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloudshell

I want view details of IAM Role to how many instances it is attached to with Cloudshell, cli which commands should use give example.

lets assume I have IAM Role TestRole I want to know to how ec2 instances TestRole is attached to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations`.

It lists Amazon EC2 instances and their associated IAM Roles (the relationship is known as an Instance Profile).

Documentation: [describe-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html)

Example output:

```json
{
    "IamInstanceProfileAssociations": [
        {
            "AssociationId": "iip-assoc-0c406f0e0208b90e6",
            "InstanceId": "i-1234abcd",
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<Account>:instance-profile/role1",
                "Id": "AIPAxxx"
            },
            "State": "associated"
        },
        {
            "AssociationId": "iip-assoc-035f9e94b2bb6f283",
            "InstanceId": "i-abcd1234",
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<Account>:instance-profile/role2",
                "Id": "AIPAxxx"
            },
            "State": "associated"
        }
    ]
```

I would recommend using this command to list *all* associations, and then check the `IamInstanceProfile` to determine whether it is using the IAM Role of interest.

Comment: @Sid if this answers your question please consider accepting it.